# GRASS 7.8.3 problem with r.watershed and r.water.outlet

Tags: grass-gis, basin, r.watershed

I need to find the basin of a small river and this is what I did:

- I found the drainage direction with r.watershed
- I used r.water.outlet to find the basin for the coordinates of the water outlet point.

The problem is that this works for some bigger rivers but not for the one I need.

I saw that in the output "stream" of r.watershed my river doesn't appear, could be it the problem? What can I do? Here the images of "accumulation" form r.watershe in which you can see the river and the images of "stream" where there river doesn't appear.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that the drainage point lies exactly on a stream line? Zoom in close to the streams raster (from `r.watershed`) and get the X-Y coordinates of the center of one pixel **on the streams line**. Then use those coordinates, together with the drainage direction raster as input to `r.water.outlet`, and it should work.

If you want to see the actual stream lines in your small basin, you'll need to rerun r.watershed with a lower `threshold` value.

Comment: Thank you very much. The problem was that there wasn't my river in the "stream" output as you can see in the first image I uploaded so I couldn't center the pixel. Using a lower threshold I resolved. Thank you again.